# Currency price conversion in html

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have html table with prices. And I want to have select-tag, using which one can choose in which currency the price is shown.

Choose currency

```
<select>
    <option value="1.">usd</option>
    <option value="1.3">euro</option>
</select>

<table>
    <tr><td>Item</td><td>Price</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Watches</td><td>100</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bike</td><td>200</td></tr>
</table>
```

I basically want a code, which, when euro is chosen, will multiply all the dollar prices by 1.3 and replace it in the table.

I kind of have a feeling that it should be done using Java script, but have no idea how. Would have been really thankful, if somebody could help.

Comment: You should at least try something, and come back if you have a more specific problem when implementing it. As is, this question does not fit Stack Overflow format.

Comment: You could definitely use some JavaScript to enable such option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn sth about js and DOM.

First add a onchange event on your select

```
<select onchange="switch_currency(this.value);">
```

Second add an id on your table

```
<table id="table_price">
```

Then use js as below

```
<script>
  var switch_currency = function(currency) {
    var table = document.getElementById("table_price");

    for (var i = 1; i < table.children[0].children.length; i++) {
      var td = table.children[0].children[i].children[1];
      td.innerHTML *= currency;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ah.. very nice solution. I kind of understand how it works, but not sure where you define currency variable in td.innerText *= currency. As I understand the call switch_currency() should have an argument in which you pass the value of multiplier, 1 or 1.3. Have a feeling, that it should be something like switch_currency(this.value) - not sure about correct syntax. am I right?

Comment: and another point - I think I should add "value" attribute to each <td> in the table, like <td value="100">100</td> and so on and retrive this before multiplication. otherwise the price will be multiplied by coefficient after each click. is this correct?

Comment: Sorry I missed the parameter, I've edited my answer.

Comment: But I'm not very sure what do you want about adding "value" attribute to each td

Comment: what I mean - if I understand your code correctly - is that td = table.children[0].children[i].children[1] reads the current contents of the field and therefore each time when I click on choice of currency, it will multiply the value again and again. in order to prevent this there should be some stable value of price which is not changed. anyway, you answer is definitely the best. sorry that I cannot mark it, since my reputation is below minimum of 15...

Comment: ups.. was able to mark is as acceptable. but my reputation does not allow me to add points to your answer)

Comment: yes, it will multiply the value again and again now. add a value attribute to each td is a good solution.

Comment: @JohnSmith haha, you have 19 now

Comment: thanks) by the way, your td.innerText did not work for me, i had to change it to td.innerHTML. you can update your answer to make it even better)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so lets say you have an input field of id `usdollar` and you want the amount entered to be multiplied by 1.3 on submit. Then you can use JavaScript to do that.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function multiply(){
  var field = document.getElementById('usdollar');
  field.value = parseInt(field.value) * 1.3;
}
</script>
<form onSubmit="multiply();">
```